# Solution file is not in the same folder as the rest of the files of the same project

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Can someone pls tell me where to set it so that my solution file gets saved in the same directory as the rest of the files of the same project.  Im using vs 2013.  Why does it get created at a different location btw?  Thanks.

Comment: thats because of the solution structuring. A solution consists of projects thats why the solution file is out of the projects folder you can read about about the structuring of solutions and project on: [Structuring Solutions and Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx)

Comment: If you are talking about a single project with a single solution file...
The solution file will not get created in a different location unless you have ticked "Create directory for solution", when you first create a project. The solution will be at the same level as the project files. I have not tried this for VS2013 but this is the same for VS2012.

Comment: Thanks alot guys.  Will check up on that link you sent Mark, and thanks for your help too Spock.